# animate() not updating fast enough

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a navigation bar that remains at the top of the page. When the user scrolls down, this bar will shrink, and when the user goes back to the top of the page, the navbar returns to its original dimensions.

**Problem:** When the user scroll down, the navbar shrinks as expected. However if the user scrolls back to the top of the page quickly, the navbar remains shrunken, and the `animate()` function within the `scrollTop()` callback function triggers after a few seconds.

To debug this, I included `console.log($(window).scrollTop());` to tell me the current position of the user on the page. I get the `console.log` output as quick as the user scrolls. **But** `{console.log('animated');` which is supposed to fire when the animation is completed, does not appear till a few seconds later after `console.log($(window).scrollTop());` outputs `0`.

How can I get `animate()` to respond quickly when the user scrolls up?

**JS Code**

```
var navBar = $('#navbar-inner');
var top = navBar.css('top');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        navBar.animate({'marginTop':'-20', 'height':'60'}, 300);
    } else {
        navBar.animate({'marginTop':'0', 'height':'80'}, 300, function() 
            {console.log('animated');});
    }
});
```

Comment: I would suggest doing `navBar.stop().animate(...` to stop any ongoing animations before starting a new one.  Not sure if that will fix your problem, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @MrOBrian: Post it as an answer so we can vote you up and OP can accept....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posting my comment as an answer)

Use `.stop()` to stop any ongoing animations before starting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this kind of issues before with animations that last longer than the user action. You just need to stop the animation, something like

```
navBar.stop(true, true).animate(...);
```

To understand stop() better here is the link http://api.jquery.com/stop/. Hope it helps